# Replace variable in text file with sbt

Tags: sbt

I have legacy SBT build file. As a part of build process I need to replace one specific string in text file. 
Specifically in Play Framework application in  public/index.html file I need to replace placeholder string to GA UUID code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom resource generator that reads your file, replaces the placeholder and writes it to a file.

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val content = IO.read(resourceDirectory.value / "index.html")
  val out = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "index.html"
  IO.write(out, content.replace("<build-time>", System.currentTimeMillis.toString))
  Seq(out)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually an additional "in Compile" is missing from the confirmed solution (contributed by Aki):

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val content = IO.read((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "index.html")
  val out = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "index.html"
  IO.write(out, content.replace("<build-time>", System.currentTimeMillis.toString))
  Seq(out)
}
```

I would have added a comment but I don't have enough "reputation" :)